# How can I create a similar material in eevee blender

Tags: rendering, animation, texturing, materials, eevee-render-engine

How can I create a similar material in EEVEE, because in Cycles high quality render takes forever so I thought of using EEVEE.

Is there any specific name for this material?

This is from Derek Elliott planet animation tutorial

https://i.stack.imgur.com/moJ5j.jpg

Comment: [How to upload an image to a post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post)

Answer (score 1):

The ring looks like a frosted glass with a low IOR. You will need to enable screen space reflections to get good looking results.

[image]

[image]